# Bind images to ListView From Local folder from Windows Universal application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am binding an observable collection to a Grid in UWP project and binding is working for string datatypes but not for ImageSource Data Type. The image is need to be loaded from a Local folder . 
The image is downloaded to Local folder via the application in some other parts [ The code is not included here ] But that downloading section is working fine

The below code is used to create the collection to bind

```
  public class LibraryBookModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }       
    public ImageSource CoverImage { get; set; }
  }   
   private ObservableCollection<LibraryBookModel> DPMBooks;
   private async Task<bool> lodLibrariesAsync(Uri library_url)
    {
        try
        {
            //create a view model object and add to observable collection
            LibraryBookModel view_model = new LibraryBookModel {  Name = "Myname", Title = "Myttile" };
            string filename =  "picture_uname.png"; //this file is present in the folder                                
            string cover_path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", COVERPICS_Folder, filename);
            view_model.CoverImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///"), cover_path));
            DPMBooks.Add(view_model);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    const string COVERPICS_Folder = "MyUniversalApp\\LabWork1\\CoverImages";
```

And xaml used is here and run time it shows both string properties correctly but not the image.

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>              
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:LibraryBookModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Width="56" Height="56">
                        <Image Source="{Binding CoverImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="9.6,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="9.6,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there anything wrong in the way image url is constructed?

Comment: Two things that come to mind. 1) Replace '\' with '/' and 2) Maybe you need to specify the folder (local | roaming | temp) in the path right after ms-appdata:/// . Like "ms-appdata:///Local/MyUniversalApp/LabWork1/CoverImages"

Comment: @Corcus YES that did the trick . BUt while saving to Local folder i have to mention it with \\

Comment: Happy to help :) Out of curiocity was it the first or the second? Or both?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. We need to use both 1) Replace '\' with '/' and 2)  specify the folder local like
  string cover_path = string.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}/{1}", COVERPICS_Folder, filename);